# Postgresql migrate production DB from development DB

Tags: postgresql, migration

I have an development database (postresql 9.3) in which I often alter tables. Now I want to migrate this new structure to the development database. The data in the production database needs to remain untouched. Any suggetions? Can I use pgdump and pgrestore for this task?

Thanks for your help
Andy

Comment: Migrate ***to*** the development database?

Comment: yeah only the structure... not the data... means I add a new column or an index to the development database and I want to transfer those changes from development database to production. In the past I did this via sql but depending on the changes it can be complicated

Answer (score 0):

One of the tool you may try is https://github.com/perseas/Pyrseas

Comment: Thanks for your help... I will have a look at it. I also found this one:

http://apgdiff.com/how_to_use_it.php

There is no build in tool in postgres? Which can do this job?

Comment: No, I'm afraid there is nothing in postgresql that can do this.